# Adding Array extension for multidimensional arrays in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, matrix

I have a matrix, ie array of arrays. I want to add some methods to better handle this as extension to `Array`. I was thinking of writting something like this:

```
extension Array where Element == Array {
    // my methods
}
```

But alas, this won't compile, since I have added recursive definition. Obviosly I can omit part `where Element == Array`, but it seems like nice touch to have these methods show only when appropriate. Is there some other way this can be achieved?

EDIT:
as per @Leo Dabus suggestion, I will provide some use case:

I have app that has multiple table view controllers. In each of them I have sections and rows. In order to populate them, I use two arrays: one for section names, and the other one is array of arrays of objects(or structs) -> corresponding sections and rows in index paths. So I want to write methods for manipulation array of arrays based on index path. For example:

```
a[indexPath] = sender
```

These objects vary, some are simple strings, some are more complex

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
extension Array where Element: Collection {
}
```

Comment: This extends arrays of dictionaries, sets, strings, ... and not just arrays of arrays

Answer (score 1):

To extend an array of arrays of objects (or structs) of type `YourType`, use this:

```
extension Array where Element == Array<YourType> { 
    //Your methods
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't allow you to use your methods with a slice of the Array

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// extension primarily for array of arrays
extension Collection where Element: Collection {
    /// all elements (rows) are of the some length
    /// - `[[1,2], [3,4]].allElementsSameLength == true`
    public var allElementsSameLength: Bool {
        guard !isEmpty else { return true }
        return dropFirst().allSatisfy { $0.count == first!.count }
    }
}
```

run on sample data:

```
// array of arrays
let data = [
    ["labe", "value", "type"],
    ["name", "joe", "String"],
    ["age", "8", "Int"]
]

let data2 = [
    ["labe", "value", "type"],
    ["name", "joe"],
    ["age", "8", "Int"]
]

let data3 = [[1,1], [3,4]]
let data4 = [[1,2,3]]            // one row only
let data5 = [[Int]]()            // no row
```

and the result is:

```
data.allElementsSameLength,     // T
data2.allElementsSameLength,    // F
data3.allElementsSameLength,    // T
data4.allElementsSameLength,    // T
data5.allElementsSameLength,    // T
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a [Contextual Where Clause](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID628) on a function, rather than a `where` on the extension. In a function context you can introduce generic parameters.

Here is an example which computes the trace of a 2D matrix:

```
public extension Array {
    func trace<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>() -> T where Element == Array<T> {
        var total: T = 0
        
        for i in 0...count {
            let row = self[i]
            total += row[i]
        }
        
        return total
    }
}
```

However, if you plan to implement 2D arrays, I strongly suggest you consider using a single array of size `cols * rows` and then indexing it appropriately.